# Group places a user has been

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregation-framework

I am wandering if its possible to collect all recorded places a user has visited and get a list of those, but if a user has been to the same place only get that place once in the output?

Here is my example data:

```
{"userId": "abc123", "visited": "Berlin"}
{"userId": "abc123", "visited": "Copenhagen"}
{"userId": "abc123", "visited": "New York"}
{"userId": "abc123", "visited": "Berlin"}
```

Now if I collect it like this I get Berlin twice:

```
var allVisits = db.Collection('visits').find( { "userId" : "abc123" };

var allCities = [];
```

I would like to get an array with all cities but only once. How can I accomplish that?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`$addToSet`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) aggregation operator with [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage.

```
db.Collection('visits').aggregate(
  { "$match": { "userId" : "abc123" }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "places": { "$addToSet": "$visited" }
  }}
)
```